# can not load private key using ssh-add

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keygen

I tried to create a ssh key by doing following command:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

then it prompts me to enter store path:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa): id_dsa
```

after I entering my passphrase, i got the following result

```
Your identification has been saved in id_dsa.
Your public key has been saved in id_dsa.pub.
```

Then i tried to load my private ssh key using the followibg command

```
ssh-add /Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa
```

It shows the result:

```
-bash: ssh-add/Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
```

When I navigate to my local diretory, Users/KesongXie, and I can not find the .ssh file(as expected , doc files are hidden ), but when I tried to view it in my terminal, I type

```
cd ~
pwd
```

I got `Users/KesongXie`
 and i tired to `ls` and expect to see my .ssh, but it's still invisible. then i tried to

```
cd .ssh
```

I found out i then entered the .ssh directory, use `ls` , i can see the following result:

```
github_rsa  github_rsa.pub  id_dsa      id_dsa.pub  known_hosts
```

the keys do store in the .ssh folder , but i wonder why i can not load the private key using

```
ssh-add /Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Answer (score 4):

If I read this correctly, you did:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa): id_dsa
```

This tells the ssh-keygen command to make an id_dsa file in the current directory. To make one in the .ssh directory, you have to simply press enter.

So now you have key files in your home directory, and you don't have a .ssh directory (at least that is what I suspect is happening)

The "cd .ssh" command will do nothing because you don't have a .ssh directory. That's why other programs complain the file does not exits.

By the way, the ls command will not show you any files that start with a dot, like ".ssh", because those files are hidden. Use "ls -a" to see hidden files.

Comment: now i have store my keys in my .ssh files, but still can not load the private key using ssh-add/Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa, it says -bash: ssh-add/Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory,my pwd is Users/KesongXie/.ssh